# DBus python unwanted blocked threads

Tags: python, multithreading, dbus

I write a simple dbus service which create several threads. But when a service starts all threads became blocked. More or less this is my service:

```
import time
import threading
import gobject
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib

dbus.mainloop.glib.threads_init()
dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)    

class DummyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DummyThread, self).__init__()
        self.__running = True

    def run(self):
        while self.__running:
            print "I'm a running thread..."
            time.sleep(1.0)

    def stop(self):
        self.__running = False

class Service(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Service, self).__init__(
            dbus.service.BusName('example.service', bus.SessionBus()),
            '/example/service')
        self.__loop = gobject.MainLoop(is_running=True)

    @dbus.service.method('example.service.Interface')
    def echo(self, data):
        print 'Received: {}'.format(str(data))
        return data

    def run(self):
        self.__loop.run()

    def quit(self):
        if self.__loop.is_running():
            self.__loop.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = Service()
    print 'Starting dummy thread...'
    dummy = DummyThread()
    dummy.start()
    print 'Starting echo service...'
    try:
        service.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '\nUser want to quit!'
    print 'Stopping services and threads...'
    dummy.stop()
    dummy.join()
    service.quit()
```

And also this is a little client:

```
import sys
import dbus

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        service = dbus.SessionBus().get_object('example.service',
                                               '/example/service')
        self.echo = service.get_dbus_method('echo', 'example.service.Interface')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    recv = client.echo(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
    print 'Received: {}'.format(recv)
```

If you run the server, no messages of the thread are showed until any client make requests to service. So my question is: is it possible to make threads independent of the gMainLoop() used by DBus?

Thank you in advance!